# Asset.fromModule is not a function. (In 'Asset.fromModule(image)', 'Asset.fromModule' is undefined)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

After updating to Expo sdk 34, I am getting this error:
`TypeError: Asset.fromModule is not a function. (In 'Asset.fromModule(image)', 'Asset.fromModule' is undefined)`.

I have ran the cod-mod which Expo recommends using this command: `npx expo-codemod sdk33-imports src` when updating to new versions, and I've also tried changing `import * as Asset from 'expo-asset';` to `import { Asset } from 'expo-asset'`, but neither of these changes have fixed this warning.

This is my App.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, Alert } from 'react-native';
import {Root} from 'native-base';
import {createRootNavigator} from './router';
import {configureFontAwesomePro} from "react-native-fontawesome-pro";
import Geocoder from 'react-native-geocoding';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
import * as Asset from 'expo-asset';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import Api from './services/api';
import Moment from 'moment';
import Config from './config/config';
import './i18n';
import store from './store/store';
import i18n from 'i18n-js';

configureFontAwesomePro();
const RootNav = createRootNavigator();

function cacheImages(images) {

    return images.map(image => {
        if (typeof image === 'string') {
            return Image.prefetch(image);
        } else {
            return Asset.fromModule(image).downloadAsync();
        }
    });
}

function cacheFonts(fonts) {
    return fonts.map(font => Font.loadAsync(font));
  }


export default class App extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            isReady: false
        };

    }

    async _loadAssetsAsync() {
        const imageAssets = cacheImages([
            require('./assets/images/splash.png'),
            require('./assets/images/splash-logo.png'),
            require('./assets/images/hotdrink.png'),
            require('./assets/images/insta.png'),
            require('./assets/images/twitter.png'),
            require('./assets/images/facebook.png'),
            require('./assets/images/yelp.png'),
        ]);

        store.updatePrefix(Expo.Linking.makeUrl('/'));

        const fontAssets = cacheFonts(
            [{
                Roboto: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto.ttf"),
                Roboto_medium: require("native-base/Fonts/Roboto_medium.ttf"),
                Ionicons: require("@expo/vector-icons")
            }]
        );

        await Promise.all([...imageAssets, ...fontAssets]);
    }

    render() {
        if (!this.state.isReady) {
            return (<AppLoading
                startAsync={this._loadAssetsAsync}
                onFinish={() => this.setState({isReady: true})}
                onError={(error) => console.log('app js: ', error)}
            />)
        }
        return (
            <Root>
                <RootNav uriPrefix={store.prefix} />
            </Root>
        )
    }
}

Geocoder.init(Config.google_maps_key);
```

**Edit:**
After making the changes suggested below: 
 - changing the import of asset from `import * as Asset from 'expo-asset';` to `import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';`
 - I am now getting this error, which is slightly different than the one
   I originally wrote about
 - `TypeError: asset.downloadAsync is not a function. (In 'asset.downloadAsync()', 'asset.downloadAsync' is undefined)`.

Comment: Just double checking, you mention trying `import { Asset } from expo-asset` but you'll need quotes around `expo-asset`. A freshly generated create-react-native-app with Expo 34 uses `import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';` FWIW

Comment: `"expo-asset"` worked for me - I was using `"expo"`.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like this should just be `import { Asset } from "expo-asset";` instead of `import * as Asset from 'expo-asset';`.

I figured this out since that `import` statement looked odd, so I copied your App.js into a fresh create-react-native-app install, added a few of the dependencies and commented out the bits that seemed unrelated or references to files that aren't posted here. I got the `TypeError: Asset.fromModule is not a function. (In 'Asset.fromModule(image)', 'Asset.fromModule' is undefined)` warning, changed the import line, and the app loaded (it didn't do much, but with so much commented out that was expected).

The `import` statement is pretty easy to accidentally get wrong without actually generating an errors on the import line, may be worth refreshing on how `as` works when using it, see [the docs on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import)

Comment: Thank you so much! That fixed that error for me! However, I am getting another one: `The "ExpoNativeModulesProxy" native module is not exported through NativeModules; verify that expo-react-native-adapter's native code is linked properly`. Do you happen to know what might be causing this new one?

Comment: I didn't see that locally, but it looks this is being [actively discussed on the Expo repo in the last few hours](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4288).

Comment: Thanks! I will follow up on their discussions then! Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Hey @Mason Stewart I've just updated my question. I noticed that the original error is gone, but now I am seeing a different error related to Asset that I can't seem to fix at all! Do you have any idea what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Run this in your root folder:

`expo install expo-asset`

And then run

`expo start -c`

just to be sure.

Answer (score -1):

try rm-rf node_modules and yarn or npm install
works 99.9% of the time